# Eclipse installation Issue -org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 code=0 java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD5 MessageDigest not available

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-2019-12

1. Below is the error log -
2. Don't know what the issue is.
3. Tried uninstalling and installinig again, yet no success

   ```
    [2020-03-06 16:55:34] ERROR: org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 code=0 java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD5 MessageDigest not available
       java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD5 MessageDigest not available
         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.License.calculateLicenseDigest(License.java:125)
         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.License.getUUID(License.java:92)
   ```

Comment: I'd make sure your JRE / JDK are up to date, it's interesting that whatever system you're installing on wouldn't support MD5

Comment: @ZacharyCraig this was working in my machine till jdk 1.8.231 version and after updating to jdk 1.8.241 it has stopped. FYI - the same works on other machines